# Refactoring LDAP/AD script from VBS to C#

Tags: c#, vbscript, active-directory, ado

I need to refactor a VBS dealing with LDAP, ADODB and ActiveDirectory from VBS to C#. The part I'm stuck is connecting (just starting and already stuck... great). This is the original source

```
Set objRootDSE = GetObject("LDAP://RootDSE")
strConfig = objRootDSE.Get("configurationNamingContext")
strDNSDomain = objRootDSE.Get("defaultNamingContext")

Set adoCommand = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
Set adoConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
adoConnection.Provider = "ADsDSOObject"

adoConnection.Open "Active Directory Provider"
adoCommand.ActiveConnection = adoConnection

strQuery = "<LDAP://dm1.com.local/OU=CN,OU=Users,OU=CMS Organizational,OU=CMS_Users_and_Groups,DC=cms,DC=local>;(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(!useraccountcontrol:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2));distinguishedName,lastLogon,whenCreated;subtree"

adoCommand.CommandText = strQuery
adoCommand.Properties("Page Size") = 100
adoCommand.Properties("Timeout") = 60
adoCommand.Properties("Cache Results") = False

Set adoRecordset = adoCommand.Execute
```

And the C# looks like this

```
DirectoryEntry dse = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://RootDSE");
string config = dse.Properties["configurationNamingContext"].Value.ToString();
string domain = dse.Properties["defaultNamingContext"].Value.ToString();
Connection connection = new Connection();
connection.Provider = "ADsDSOObject";
connection.Open("ADsDSOObject", "", "", 0);

object records, parameters = "";

ADODB.Command command = new Command();
command.ActiveConnection = connection;
command.CommandText = "<LDAP://dm1.com.local/OU=CN,OU=Users,OU=CMS Organizational,OU=CMS_Users_and_Groups,DC=cms,DC=local>;(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(!useraccountcontrol:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2));distinguishedName,lastLogon,whenCreated;subtree";
command.Execute(out records, ref parameters, 0);
```

It gives me the error

```
Interface not supported (Provider)
 at ADODB.CommandClass.Execute(Object& RecordsAffected, Object& Parameters, Int32 Options)
at Adug.Program.Main(String[] args) in E:\...\Program.cs:line 66
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have no experience with querying LDAP via ADO, but I have used the following code successfully (simplified here), which makes use of `DirectorySearcher`:

```
DirectoryEntry directoryEntry = new DirectoryEntry(
      config.DirectoryConnectionString, 
      config.ActiveDirectoryUserName, 
      config.GetPassword(), 
      AuthenticationTypes.Secure);
DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher(directoryEntry);

ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add("cn");
ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add("sAMAccountName");
ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add("mail");
ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add("displayName");

ds.Filter = "(objectClass=user)";

foreach (SearchResult result in ds.FindAll())
{
    string displayName = String.Empty;
    DirectoryEntry entry = result.GetDirectoryEntry();
    if (entry.Properties.Contains("displayName"))
            if (entry.Properties["displayName"].Count > 0)
                displayName  = entry.Properties["displayName"][0].ToString();
}
```

Comment: Changing the ds.Filter from objectClass=user to objectCategory=person will result in an indexed search and will be significantly faster.

Comment: Thanks @Dscoduc, my knowledge of the DirectorySearcher is sorely lacking, always good to learn something new.

Comment: In fact, you should use both - (&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)). Windows 2008+ DCs have a mandatory index on objectClass so it's less of a problem, but, you'll get other stuff (e.g. computers, trusts, etc).

Comment: In addition to Brian's comment I added `(sAMAccountName=" & UserName & ")` and called `FindOne` instead of `FindAll` then grabbed the resulting values like so `result.Properties("mail").Item(0)`. Also, it's important to understand your security implementation on your domain controller as this may prevent you from making this function call via the server from another machine when using Impersonation.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `System.DirectoryServices` namespace is the preferred method for accessing Active Directory in .NET. **Daniel B**'s answer should get you moving in the right direction.